# Azure Data Sync To Tables with Different Name and Schemas

Tags: azure, azure-data-sync

I'm trying to create a **SYNC** on Azure. I have 3 different databases on prod.

I want to move some tables of those DBs to reporting environment with different schema and different table names. Let's assume I have 3 Dbs names A, B , C. I will move their tables to schemas

- A Table1 => Reporting Db A.Table1("A" as a schema name)
- A Table2=> Reporting Db A.Table2
- B.Table5 => Reporting Db B.Table5
- etc..

Shortly, I want to configure SYNC, I want to select which table to sync which table, even columns.

Is there any way to do it?

When I try to create a SYNC from UI, It doesn't show me an option.